# Hide or show span inside of repeater on checkbox change via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, checkbox, repeater

I have an asp repeater that is populated from a hashtable containing names of school classes (Key) and the description of those classes (Value). I want to show/hide the descriptions that are encapsulated in a span based on if a checkbox input is checked or not.

I have managed to pass the current repeaters iteration number by passing Container.ItemIndex as a parameter to my JS method in hope that I could get the repeater collection and just reference the ID of the span at that index.

I have also tried naming the ID of the span as "string" + Container.ItemIndex hoping I could get the span that way but also no luck.

Below is my aspx code, please help me hide/show the spnMoreInfo span of the repeater iteration that the user has checked or unchecked the checkbox of in JavaScript.

````
```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="rptClassList" >
    <ItemTemplate>

        <span class="text-center;" style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: 200"><%#((DictionaryEntry)Container.DataItem).Key%></span>

        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" runat="server" CssClass="rpContacts" onchange='<%# "return HideShow(" + Container.ItemIndex + ")" %>'>
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label><br/>

        <span runat="server" id="spnMoreInfo" class="text-center;" style="display: none"><%#((DictionaryEntry)Container.DataItem).Value%> </span>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```
````

Answer (score 1):

In the end I went was able to dynamically name the IDs of the controls as a string + the current repeaters iteration number. I was previously hindered by the fact that I was using runat=server. I then changed the display attribute based on the checked status in my JavaScript method. Here is the code and the onscreen view.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="rptClassList" >
    <ItemTemplate>

        <br/><span class="text-center;" style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: 200"><%#((DictionaryEntry)Container.DataItem).Key%></span>

        <label class="switch">
            <%--Make the ID of the checkbox = a string plus the current iteration number of the repeater and pass that iteration number in the client side method--%>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkHideShow<%# (Container).ItemIndex%>" onchange='<%# "return HideShow(" + Container.ItemIndex + ")" %>'>
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label><br/>

        <span id="spnMoreInfo<%# (Container).ItemIndex%>" class="text-center" style="display: none"><%#((DictionaryEntry)Container.DataItem).Value%> <br/></span> 

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function HideShow(selectedIteration) {

        var checkbox = document.getElementById("chkHideShow" + selectedIteration).checked;
        var span = document.getElementById("spnMoreInfo" + selectedIteration);

        if (checkbox == false) {
            span.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            span.style.display = "inline";
        }

    }
</script>
```

**Unchecked:**

[image: Unchecked]

**Checked:**

[image: Checked]

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `span` of interest inside repeater item and then hide/show it using javascript. Something like this.

```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="rptClassList" >
    <ItemTemplate>
       <div><%--wrap repeater item --%>
        <span class="text-center;" style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: 200"><%#((DictionaryEntry)Container.DataItem).Key%></span>

        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" runat="server" CssClass="rpContacts" onchange='<%# "return HideShow(" + Container.ItemIndex + ")" %>'>
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label><br/>

        <span runat="server" id="spnMoreInfo" class="text-center descr"><%#((DictionaryEntry)Container.DataItem).Value%> </span>
      </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<script>
   function toggleShow(el){
     var item = el.parentNode.parentNode;//you know where is the item
     if(!el.checked)
        item.querySelector('.descr').style.display = 'none';
     else
        item.querySelector('.descr').style.display = 'inline';//default for span
   }
   window.onload = function(){
     var repeater = document.getElementById('<%#rptClassList.ClientID%>');//or hardcode it
     var chks = repeater.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]');
     for(var i = 0, chk; chk = chks[i]; ++i){
       toggleShow(chk);
       chk.addEventListener('click', function(){
           toggleShow(this);
       });
     }//for
   };//window.onload
```